# how to create uninstall webhook in shopify using laravel wrapper?

Tags: laravel-5.3, shopify

i am trying to create webhook using the api call inlaravel but it gives me the error  "The requested URL returned error: 406 Not Acceptable".
my code is as bellow.

```
$webhookData = [
        'webhook' => [
        'topic' => 'app/uninstalled',
        'address' => url('/uninstall'),
        'fields' => 'name',
        'format' => 'json'
        ]
    ];
 $uninstall = $sh->call(['URL' =>  'https://' . $shop . '/admin/webhooks.json', 'METHOD' => 'POST', 'DATA' => $webhookData]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are certain things you need to take care of while creating the Shopify webhooks.

- The address field should be a globally accessible URL (ex: https://example.com/webhook/uninstall.php)
- You can not give localhost links for creating webhooks.

I think the address field is not passed with a valid URL in your post request.

Comment: it is my rout not the localhoast url